# How to update DataGridView correctly, so GUI doesn't freeze

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, freeze

I have a backgroundworker, which does some calculations and reports progress result as string. This string needs to be inserted into dataGridView. But while inserting values, GUI freezes.

```
private void bckgrSorter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        // doing some calculations
        bckgrSorter.ReportProgress(i, someString);
    }
}    

 private void bckgrSorter_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     string results = (string)e.UserState;
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(results);
 }
```

So even though I do all the heavy calculations on a background thread, GUI still freezes, because of DataGridView.

**Edit for code:**

```
private void bckgrSorter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] folders = // some folders to get File List from

        bckgrFileScanner.RunWorkerAsync(folders);            
    }

private void bckgrFileScanner_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] folders = (string[])e.Argument;
        foreach (string f in folders)
        {
            GetFileList(ref scannedFiles, f, bckgrFileScanner);
            bckgrFileScanner.ReportProgress(1);
        }
    }

public void GetFileList(ref List<FileInfo> fList, string fPath, BackgroundWorker scanner)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fPath);
            FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo fiTemp in fi)
            {
                //ar ~$ saakas nevajadzīgie temp faili, tos izlaižam
                if (fiTemp.Name.StartsWith("~$") == false)
                {
                    fList.Add(fiTemp);
                    scanner.ReportProgress(0, fiTemp.Name);
                }
            }
            DirectoryInfo[] dFolders = di.GetDirectories();

            //katrai apakšmapei rekursīvi izsaucam šo funkciju
            foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dFolders)
            {
                GetFileList(ref fList, d.FullName, scanner);
            }
        }

private void bckgrFileScanner_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
        {
            filesDataGrid.Rows.Add(e.UserState);
        }

        else progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
```

Comment: One reason might be that you are adding all rows at a time. The grid will first add all rows, then refresh itself, I suppose. Do you want to see rows being inserted one by one in the grid?

Comment: Yes, to see rows adding one by one would also be nice, but primary wish is that GUI is not freezed while performing updates and inserts.

Comment: Can you post an executable code sample so that we can check it?

Comment: Check my edit for code example

Comment: I've run into similar problems myself, and it seems to me the bottleneck is actually WPF's rendering, which stalls the UI while it is happening, and I haven't been able to find a reliable way around it. Would love if someone had a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you need to batch up the results from your worker thread. Maybe you could make the ProgressChanged event return a collection of progress results or something? Or only have the event fire at most every half a second with the latest data. I suspect the problem is that you're just trying to add data too fast. You need to do less units of work with more work in each unit (add lots of rows in one go).

Babar is right. Something like this would probably do what you want (I haven't tried to compile it):

```
    public void GetFileList(ref List<FileInfo> fList, string fPath, BackgroundWorker scanner)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fPath);
        FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();

        List<string> progressData = new List<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo fiTemp in fi)
        {
            //ar ~$ saakas nevajadzigie temp faili, tos izlaižam
            if (fiTemp.Name.StartsWith("~$") == false)
            {
                fList.Add(fiTemp);
                progressData.Add(fiTemp.Name);
                if (progressData.Count > 50){
                    scanner.ReportProgress(0, progressData.ToArray());
                    progressData.Clear();//You've just copied the data to an array and sent it to the GUI, clear the list and start counting up again
                }
            }
        }

        if (progressData.Count > 0){
            scanner.ReportProgress(0, progressData.ToArray());
        }

        DirectoryInfo[] dFolders = di.GetDirectories();

        //katrai apakšmapei rekursivi izsaucam šo funkciju
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dFolders)
        {
            GetFileList(ref fList, d.FullName, scanner);
        }
    }
```

It's not really a very good solution but it's a start...

You will need to cast e.UserState to a string array in your callback as well...

Comment: I tried to use list of string, on ProgressChanged it adds reported string to list, and checks if List.Count>50 , it adds all strings to DataGridView and clears List. Seems to work and GUI is responsive.

Comment: @andree: Instead of collecting paths in the ProgressChanged(). It would be better that you populate the list in DoWork() and pass the list as UserState to ProgressChanged(). It will simplify your ProgressChanged() logic.

Comment: You could really do with rethinking your solution adree but the hack above would allow you to batch up your work in lots of 50 (mostly) and is thread safe so you wont need to lock your list (the array is a copy of the data from the list so you are not reading data that is being altered in another thread).

Comment: Main problem is that loading huge amount of data in DataGridView is slow. Maybe I could use something like paging to display data. Lets say, only 1 small DataGridView with 50 rows, with page numbers below. All huge file list is loaded in List<FileInfo> (loading is actually pretty fast). For example, when I request files from page 2, DataGridView loads FileInfos 49-99 from my List<FileInfo>.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding file names to the grid as soon as those are discovered. On a reasonably sized directory this will easily overload UI thread with the requests to adding rows in grid. As a result your UI freezes.

Here is how you should update the code. Instead of calling ReportProgress() for individual file, the code should maintain an list of files discovered so far. Once the list gets to a threshold size say 100, then you should call the ReportProgress() and pass that list as UserState.

This will significantly reduce the number of calls to UI thread, making your application responsive.

Comment: There is a problem. I can pass my list, but accessing items creates runtime error, because list is still being changed by backgroundworker

Comment: You need to lock any access to the list. Take a look at this for an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678022/unresponsive-ui-when-too-fast-and-too-much-data-needs-to-be-updated/5678115#5678115

Comment: But then I won't be able to update the list for further changes from backgroundworker. So I need different solution.

Comment: I think locking should be fine. Locks will enable only one thread to access the list at a time, either your background thread will be writing to the list or the UI thread will read from the list and will add items to data grid. If you don't like locking, you may try making a copy of the list and passing the copy in ReportProgress().

Comment: Using a lock doesn't completely negate the effect of multiple threads, it simply means that the two threads cannot access/modify the list *at the same time*, but they can certainly do other things at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there a control property that temporarily stops the control from updating? Sadly I can't recall the name.

You could also try to create the control in background and add it to the form once it is completed. Be careful to avoid threading issues though.

Another idea would be to hide it during the update.

An ugly solution that definitely "works" would be to have your background thread add one item at a time, wait for a few milliseconds (during which the GUI thread can actually perform the change), and add the next item. It will take a long time, but the GUI won't freeze during the update.

Comment: I checked all controls for DataGridView, and it seems like there isn't one.

Comment: Since a lot of rows are added and performance is important in my application, waiting after each row would increase method execution time, so it doesn't work for me. Will try hiding it though