# How to parse high speed of data when get my process output

Tags: c#, winforms

my class start new process (Tshark) and start capturing, from the main form i am checking the class properties in order to update my UI, my only indication how many packet received is my process output:

```
Frame 13: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits)
    Arrival Time: Oct  8, 2012 01:16:42.143822000 Jerusalem Standard Time
    Epoch Time: 1349651802.143822000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.002140000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.002140000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.038739000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 13
    Frame Length: 62 bytes (496 bits)
    Capture Length: 62 bytes (496 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: eth:ip:udp:data]
Ethernet II, Src: CameoCom_fd:ae:5c (00:18:e7:fd:ae:5c), Dst: AsustekC_82:c2:2b (48:5b:39:82:c2:2b)
    Destination: AsustekC_82:c2:2b (48:5b:39:82:c2:2b)
        Address: AsustekC_82:c2:2b (48:5b:39:82:c2:2b)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Source: CameoCom_fd:ae:5c (00:18:e7:fd:ae:5c)
        Address: CameoCom_fd:ae:5c (00:18:e7:fd:ae:5c)
        .... ...0 .... .... .... .... = IG bit: Individual address (unicast)
        .... ..0. .... .... .... .... = LG bit: Globally unique address (factory default)
    Type: IP (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 84.229.2.201 (84.229.2.201), Dst: 192.168.0.100 (192.168.0.100)
    Version: 4
    Header length: 20 bytes
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP 0x00: Default; ECN: 0x00: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport))
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0x00)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not-ECT (Not ECN-Capable Transport) (0x00)
    Total Length: 48
    Identification: 0x64e7 (25831)
    Flags: 0x00
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .0.. .... = Don't fragment: Not set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 120
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0xc51b [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 84.229.2.201 (84.229.2.201)
    Destination: 192.168.0.100 (192.168.0.100)
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 26120 (26120), Dst Port: 62587 (62587)
    Source port: 26120 (26120)
    Destination port: 62587 (62587)
    Length: 28
    Checksum: 0xcfeb [validation disabled]
        [Good Checksum: False]
        [Bad Checksum: False]
Data (20 bytes)
    Data: 2100b45be8e8038b9e370ec70000f0005da90013
    [Length: 20]

0000  48 5b 39 82 c2 2b 00 18 e7 fd ae 5c 08 00 45 00   H[9..+.....\..E.
0010  00 30 64 e7 00 00 78 11 c5 1b 54 e5 02 c9 c0 a8   .0d...x...T.....
0020  00 64 66 08 f4 7b 00 1c cf eb 21 00 b4 5b e8 e8   .df..{....!..[..
0030  03 8b 9e 37 0e c7 00 00 f0 00 5d a9 00 13         ...7......]...
```

in this example "Frame 13" mean that this is packet number 13 and each packet received look like this example.

this is the relevant part of my class how start the Tshark process and start capturing:

```
            Process tshark = new Process();
            tshark.StartInfo.FileName = _tshark;
            tshark.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" -i " + _interfaceNumber + " -V -x -s " + _packetLimitSize + " -w " + _pcapPath);
            tshark.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            tshark.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            tshark.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            tshark.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            tshark.Start();
            while (!myStreamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                _packet = myStreamReader.ReadLine();

                if (_packet.StartsWith("    Frame Number:"))
                {
                    string[] arr = _packet.Split(default(char[]), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    _receivesPackets = int.Parse(arr[2]);
                    _packetsCount++;
                }

                if ((DateTime.Now - lastUpdate).TotalMilliseconds > 1000)
                {
                    lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                    OnPacketProgress(_packetsCount++);
                }
            }

            tshark.WaitForExit();
```

the code **if (_packet.StartsWith("    Frame Number:"))** inside the StreamReader while loop parse the packet number from the packet, put in the relevant property (_packetsCount) and from the main form i am checking this property every 1 second and update my UI, my problem is in case of very very high speed the UI didn't update all the packets for example after 2 mun of capturing the UI show ~50,000 and the created file has more than 1,000,000.
Is there a more efficient way for me to parse/receive these data and it become more accurate ?

Comment: What do "speen" and "ger" mean?

Comment: How about this idea - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5678115/763026 ?